# scipy odeint: sum of conservative ode equations does not remain zero -- is this normal?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Let us say we have the following equations:

```
dy1/dt = f(y1, t)      [1]
dy2/dt = g(y2, t)      [2]
```

The equations are such that they are "conservative", i.e. the following condition should hold:

```
dy1/dt + dy2/dt = 0    [3]
```

Using `scipy.odeint`, I find that I can integrate conservative equations like this just fine for simple systems of ODEs.

However, for larger ones, I get the following issue.

Let's say that this is my derivative function:

```
def deriv_function(y0s, t):
    ...body defines equations 1, and 2...

    print np.sum(ode)
    return ode
```

Note the print statement.

I use `scipy.odeint` on `deriv_function` as follows:

```
odeint(deriv_fun, y0s, [0, 0.5])
```

Due to the print statement, the following gets printed out:

```
-1.38555833473e-13 <--- note, close to zero
-0.00679107743937
-0.0067907211796
-0.0135814423985
-0.0135810861584
-0.416522145214
-0.416523165887
-0.818209018574
-0.818211056221
-1.21864678558
-1.21864881584
-2.86735888212
-2.8673729885
-2.46855840934
-2.46856658088
-3.70632102566
-3.70631206163
-4.93200749506
-4.93200691488
-6.14577326158
-6.14577268283
-8.53799987128
-8.53799713959
-10.8839304356
-10.8839320212
-13.1845005689
-13.1845021725
-15.4406122011
-15.4406123927
-17.6531469917
-17.653147185
-24.6238415795
-24.6238498033
-31.1628867985
-31.1628947266
-37.2974784594
-37.2974547092
-35.463527103
-35.4635192949
-39.5777426955
-39.5777472677
-43.5137135424
-43.5137108017
-47.2791485087
-47.2791483993
-50.881424906
-50.8814244751
-54.3275507164
-54.3275502654    <--- note, not close to zero
```

For smaller systems of equations (not the same), the following gets printed out:

```
-1.13686837722e-13
0.0
0.0
0.0
-1.13686837722e-13
1.13686837722e-13
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
-1.13686837722e-13
0.0
0.0
0.0
1.13686837722e-13
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
-1.13686837722e-13
0.0
0.0
-1.13686837722e-13
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
-1.13686837722e-13
0.0
0.0
5.68434188608e-14
-5.68434188608e-14
-5.68434188608e-14
0.0
```

I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out if the issue has something to do with the way I have defined the equations, and I am now fairly certain that this is not the case. In order to confirm this, I would like to ask: is it possible at all for a non-conservative system of equations to first print an ode sum that is close to zero, but later print values that are not close to zero?

Another way to think of the question: in the larger system of equations, the ode sum initial prints out to be approximately zero, before increasing. What could be happening in the bowels of the solver for this problem to be occurring?

---

To posterity: [have a look at the paralell discussion here at scicomp.stackexchange too](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/12938/scipy-odeint-sum-of-conservative-ode-equations-does-not-remain-zero-as-it-is-be).

Comment: If dy1/dt + dy2/dt = 0, then y1(t)+y2(t) = C = y1(0)+y2(0) (a constant that depends on the initial conditions), so you could solve the differential equation for, say, just y1(t), and then y2(t) = C - y1(t).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser That is exactly what I did in the end! Since I had a bit more of a complicated system, using scipy.odeint would have been a little painful to manage all the extra parameters etc. [So I ended up using PyDSTool](https://sourceforge.net/p/pydstool/discussion/472291/thread/f9332493/). Works okay for now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far my understanding on the theory of differential equations goes: You cannot determine deviations of your solution unless you have some additional constraint (like in your example).

Generally, it can be said that integration always has to cope with numeric errors. Especially in higher dimensions and when having badly behaved integrands (e.g. near poles), numeric errors can be become dominant very quickly. This is a key problem for many simulation tasks  and requires specialized methods for each class of problems (e.g. see [scipy.integrate.ode](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html#scipy.integrate.ode)).

You also could try a symbolic approach, check out [Sympy's ODE Module](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/ode.html#module-sympy.solvers.ode) for that.

Comment: If I understand correctly though, Sympy cannot solve *systems* of ODEs?

Comment: The ODE Module cannot unless you can decouple them (like in your example).

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing are numerical errors. I don't know what you mean by "larger equations", but if you mean big long expressions, you are probably going to have roundoff in the evaluation of the function (you can easily check this). If this is the case, work the maths to get a better more accurate expression.

Another thing is that you are integrating two equations at the same time. If you can decouple them, solve them independently. The algorithm has an adaptive step selection, and this value may be different from using one or many equations: when you have more than one equation, the step has to be *good enough* for *all* of them.

Regarding your question about the bowels, look at the integral curves. Here is [an example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442966/bifurcation-of-integral-curves) from MathSE

[image]

If you are near a bifurcation, a small error in the initial conditions can give you fairly different results, and they may or may not converge back.

There is no general way to solve it. I think your first bet is on analysis: use the structure present in the equations to simplify them. Or if you have poles near your trajectory, apply a transformation to push them away. On the other hand, this difference can give you an estimation of the error on the integral.

Comment: Thanks for this really nice answer! I will set a small bounty on this question as soon as I can, as I would like to really reward your answer.